# Serve Django site using Nginx without proxy_pass

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have done the nginx configuration for serving django app .i am able to serve the django site using proxy pass for that i have to run the server manualy and then nginx serves the site.I want to execute the site using nginx but the server should get start automaticaly it shoud not be go through proxy_pass is this possible .please suggest some solution.

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you try to serve your development server through nginx; That's not what it's for, it's for development purposes only.

To set up a production server you could use

- gunicorn in combination with supervisord to keep everything running (my preferred way of working these days), tutorial here: http://kencochrane.net/blog/2011/06/django-gunicorn-nginx-supervisord-fabric-centos55/
- use good ol' Apache and a .wsgi file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/
- use uWSGI, this is already in nginx but I have no experience with this one. Here a tutorial to check it out: http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/03/05/django-uwsgi-nginx/

Both gunicorn and apache are very stable in production environments if used correctly, these are my experiences though.

Comment: Yes you are right ....actually i am not deploying on production for local one i am trying to use hardcode proxy_pass address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state your OS, so... having deployed django behind both apache and nginx in *Windows*, I have to say that I found nginx to be infinitely easier.  However, since nginx is more of a static file server with excellent proxying capability, I ran a separate wsgi server for the django app.  After trying several (and finding they were unix-only), I found CheryPy's wsgi server (which can be used independently of rest of CherryPy) to work just fine (and it's pretty fast, to boot).

Comment: I am sorry about that i am using Ubuntu